# Digikam Geotag, drag and drop not working

Tags: digikam

I use Digikam 5 to organize my fotos. Recently I started to use the geotagging function, but what isn't working is to drag and drop fotos on the right position of the google maps window. Window freezes. So I can't find a method to asign coordinates, in case that there are no search results for the given position. Any hint's?

Answer (score 0):

Google plugin seems to have problems, but there is a way to get it done, as I found out:
1. Select image, open the geotagging window (Ctrl + Shift + G) and surf to the desired position in googleearth-view.
2. Change interface to 'Marble virtual globe'.
3. Drag'n'drop would't work either, but right click, then select 'copy coordinates' (this drop down menu is missing in the google interface).
4. Paste coordinates to image.
5. Now 'Reverse geocoding' to create tags (not necesary, but a very nice feature).
6. Apply.

Comment: Marble isn't adequate... in many cases it has old data, and in any case, I can't accurately pin-point some locations without actual satellite data.  Man I had such high hopes of this software, until I found this [abominable example](http://digikam.1695700.n4.nabble.com/Bug-278976-New-Right-click-geolocation-context-menu-not-available-when-using-Google-Maps-td3708486.html) of how open source developers close bugs with insolent claims like "irrelevancy"